# How to share a folder in libvirt+qemu/kvm with Linux guest and Linux host?

Tags: kvm, qemu, libvirt, plan9

I am running a VM on a Linux host using `qemu+kvm` and `libvirt`, the guest system is CentOS 7. I wish to share a folder between the two such that `host:/some/dir` becomes accessible as `guest:/some/other/dir`.

I wish to minimise effort and cannot re-compile the kernel on either side.  I experimented with `plan9` but cannot get it to run (the `p9 dkms` module won't compile on the CentOS 7 guest).

There must be a better way?  Performance is secondary as it does not work at all right now.

Answer (score 1):

Just set up sshfs/samba/nfs/etc, it's easier and it just works

EDIT: The point here is, just use a regular file share between the host and the VM, there is absolutely no need to go into dirty untested hacks like plan9.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure it doesn't answer the question, but it should probably be edited to provide a more complete answer.

Comment: This does provide an answer, the o/p wanted a way to share a directory between the VM and the host. I'm not sure full instructions on how to set up a file share or every sort imaginable will be feasible in this context, the point of the answer is to just say "use a regular file share".

Comment: Thanks, this could be a solution (but isn't, yet).  I already have Samba running but services on the host should not be accessible by the guest. Maybe `qemu`'s built-in Samba server could be an option? I searched but could not find a way to enable it using `libvirt`/`virsh`'s XML config file.

Comment: Built in samba server in QEMU? Since when?

Comment: @dyasny My source: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/165554/shared-folder-between-qemu-windows-guest-and-linux-host but there is no XML config file equivalent, and I could not generate one so far.  Documentation is hard to come by.

Comment: PS: The `qemu(1)` man page also has the `-net` `smb=dir` option, but how do I enter this into `libvirt`'s XML config file?

Comment: Well, this is pretty unusual, I've no idea why they would bloat the code with this nonsense. However, if you want to insert arbitrary qemu commands into the XML, there's a way to do that: https://libvirt.org/drvqemu.html#qemucommand

Answer (score 0):

For Centos 8 or later, you can use virtiofs to realize that: https://libvirt.org/kbase/virtiofs.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that. The guest in question is CentOS 7 but I will revisit this issue when upgrading.