# Shared folder in QEMU between Windows Host and Debian Guest

Tags: debian, windows, qemu

How do you share between the two?
I have booted my image on my Windows 10 host using this: `qemu-system-x86_64 -hda debian.img -m 512 -net user,smb=C:\users\jason\Desktop\sharing\ -net nic,model=virtio`

In the guest I tried to connect to Samba through this:

```
smbclient //10.0.2.4/qemu
```

This returns

```
Connection to 10.0.2.4 failed (Error NT_STATUS_HOST_UNREACHABLE)
```

I also tried `smbclient //10.0.2.15/qemu`
which returned

```
DOMAIN=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Windows 6.1] Server=[Samba 4.5.16-Debian]
tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME
```

The `/tmp` and `/mnt` directories remain empty.

Comment: Does this help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/165554/shared-folder-between-qemu-windows-guest-and-linux-host TL;DR: samba or RDP.

Comment: That didn't help as the host is Linux. I'm using the inbuilt Samba on Qemu.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce -- please add the output if `ip link` inside the guest to your question, or mention if the network otherwise works inside the guest (are you able to `wget https://www.google.com`?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just dealt with this problem, so I'd like to put the answer here, as the documentation does not make it obvious.

As you may know, Windows supports setting up SMB shares natively through Explorer (the "Sharing" option in the right-click menu for a directory). [This link](https://gist.github.com/neelabhg/8c6bfcdb44c0aa3f86bed00fe1f6da49), found in a GitHub Gist collection, suggests that the proper way to share from Windows host to a guest is to access the host computer *directly*, using the address 10.0.2.2, rather than using the qemu SMB share, which doesn't seem to start properly on a Windows host.

So, The solution is --

1. Share the directory you want to be shared as if you were setting it up to be shared with a physical machine.
2. Use the address 10.0.2.2 from your guest, specifying the name of the share rather than "qemu."

I just tested this from a Windows 10 host to a Windows PE guest, and it worked like a charm. Obviously, you'd have to set up the share permissions correctly, but this is pretty simple from the sharing dialog.